# Adding sparklines with min-max indicators to stylized dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data and code to produce a stylized df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan

a=rec.array([( 0, 'Q1', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  748038),
           ( 1, 'Q1', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',    9398),
           ( 2, 'Q1', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   40963),
           ( 3, 'Q1', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    6432),
           ( 4, 'Q1', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   22786),
           (25, 'Q2', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  790338),
           (26, 'Q2', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',    8931),
           (27, 'Q2', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   14512),
           (28, 'Q2', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    8173),
           (29, 'Q2', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   23079),
           (50, 'Q3', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  791992),
           (51, 'Q3', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',   12382),
           (52, 'Q3', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   14120),
           (53, 'Q3', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    5807),
           (54, 'Q3', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   20165),
           (75, 'Q4', 'FY20',  0., 'Industry Class Unknown',  515678),
           (76, 'Q4', 'FY20', 11., 'Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing & Hunting',   14242),
           (77, 'Q4', 'FY20', 21., 'Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction',   11214),
           (78, 'Q4', 'FY20', 22., 'Utilities',    4186),
           (79, 'Q4', 'FY20', 23., 'Construction',   14454)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('fy_qtr', 'O'), ('fy', 'O'), ('naics_2', '<f8'), ('naics_desc', 'O'), ('quantity', '<i4')])

# Convert array to df
df_final=pd.DataFrame.from_records(a)
df_final.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_final['metric'] = 'Sales_Volume'
df_final["naics_2"] = df_final["naics_2"].astype(int)

# Pivot df
summary_table = pd.pivot(df_final, index=['metric','naics_2','naics_desc'],columns=['fy', 'fy_qtr'])
summary_table.columns = summary_table.columns.droplevel(0)

# Apply styles

def left(v):
     return "text-align: left"
def center(v):
     return "text-align: center"


summary_table = (
     summary_table.style.set_table_styles(
         [
             dict(selector="th.index_name.level0", props=[("text-align", "center")]),
             dict(selector="th.index_name.level2", props=[("text-align", "left")]),
         ]
     )
     .format("{:,.0f}", subset=("Sales_Volume",))
     .set_properties(**{"text-align": "center"})

 )

summary_table.columns.names = ["", ""]               
summary_table
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I want to add a column on the right side of the df to show sparklines by industry over time.  Also I would like the lines to show min-max (where red=min, green=max) for each industry's values, similar to this:

[image]

How would you do this?

Comment: Kindly have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227295/adding-sparkline-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Sparkline to Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227295/adding-sparkline-to-pandas-dataframe)